# react: использование компонент без их импорта, чтобы не тащить большие портянки кода

Tags: reactjs, импорт, модули, компоненты

Подскажите можно ли в react реализовать следующий подход:

у меня есть базовый компонент `MyBaseComponent`, который я оформил как абстрактный класс (задал метод `_base_render()` который в базовом выбрасывает исключение)

от `MyBaseComponent` наследую свой компонент `MyComponent`, который использует очень много других моих компонентов, которые взаимодействуют с базовым классом

```
_base_render()
{
    return (
        <MyElement1>
            <MyElement2>
            <MyElement3>
            <MyElement4>
        </MyElement1>
    );
}
```

и т.д.

Сейчас мне приходится в .js файле, где описан `MyComponent` (или любой другой компонент - наследник `MyBaseComponent`) делать много импортов

```
import MyBaseComponent from './MyBaseComponent'
import MyElement1 from './MyElement1'
import MyElement2 from './MyElement2'
import MyElement3 from './MyElement3'
import MyElement4 from './MyElement4'
```

Что как-то несколько отягощает код.

**Подскажите** а есть ли какой-то способ избавиться от этих импортов, т.е. чтобы мне хватало только одного импорта

```
import MyBaseComponent from './MyBaseComponent'
```

и я получал доступ ко всем необходимым компонентам, т.е.

1) чтобы сделать что-то такое:

```
_base_render()
{
    return (
        <MyBaseComponent.MyElement1>
            <MyBaseComponent.MyElement2>
            <MyBaseComponent.MyElement3>
            <MyBaseComponent.MyElement4>
        </MyBaseComponent.MyElement1>
    );
}
```

2) аналогично п.1, но без `MyBaseComponent.`

Comment: импортировать в другом файле все импорты и использовать в этом файле один импорт

Comment: @Tvseans, не помогает - вылезает такая ошибка
`Line 20:  'MyElement1' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В нормальном виде возможен только первый вариант. 
Второй тоже можно, но я крайне не советую использовать его, т.к. он выльется во множество проблем.

#### Первый вариант

Создаем модуль, который собирает в себе нужные компоненты:
**MyComponents/index.js**

```js
import MyComponent1 from "./MyComponent1";
import MyComponent2 from "./MyComponent2";
import MyComponent3 from "./MyComponent3";

export default {
  MyComponent1,
  MyComponent2,
  MyComponent3
};
```

Импортируем его там, где хотим использовать свои компоненты:

```js
import React from "react";
import MyComponents from "./MyComponents";

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <MyComponents.MyComponent1 />
    <MyComponents.MyComponent2 />
    <MyComponents.MyComponent3 />
  </div>
);
```

Весь код: https://codesandbox.io/s/vnp5ny2rq7

#### Второй вариант

Повторюсь, его я крайне не рекомендую использовать, но покажу, что он реализуем.
А реализовать его можно при помощи глобальной области видимости, в нашем случае сейчас это window.
Создаем модуль, который собирает в себе нужные компоненты и записывает их в глобальную область: 
**MyComponents/index.js**

```js
import MyComponent1 from "./MyComponent1";
import MyComponent2 from "./MyComponent2";
import MyComponent3 from "./MyComponent3";

window.MyComponent1 = MyComponent1;
window.MyComponent2 = MyComponent2;
window.MyComponent3 = MyComponent3;
```

И тогда мы сможем писать вот так:

```
import React from "react";
import "./MyComponents";

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <MyComponent1 />
    <MyComponent2 />
    <MyComponent3 />
  </div>
);
```

Весь код: https://codesandbox.io/s/5kpm940ywl

Замечания по этому способу:

1. Не true way. Теряется вся инкапсуляция, непонятно откуда эти компоненты берутся, в вашей системе теперь плюс один костыль.
2. Если стоит `eslint`, то нужно отключить правило: `react/jsx-no-undef`, в начале файла пишем: `/* eslint react/jsx-no-undef: 0 */`. Но тогда если мы опечатаемся, то ошибку заметим только в рантайме.
3. Если у вас еще серверный рендер, то нужно помнить, что глобальный скоп тогда будет отличаться.
4. В случае tree shaking, нужно пометить модуль `MyComponents` как side-effect модуль.

В общем с этим способом добавляется еще ряд проблем, поэтому его не берите, используйте первый способ.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, наверное первый способ - это самое малое зло. Возможно можно ещё сделать как с `import Rect, {Component}`, чтобы не писать `MyComponents.`, но тогда длинный import будет

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вашу проблему, можно поступить следующим образом:

Создадим файл `MyBaseComponenеKit.js` в котором один раз импортируем нужные компоненты

```
// MyBaseComponenеKit.js
import MyBaseComponent from './MyBaseComponent'
import MyElement1 from './MyElement1'
import MyElement2 from './MyElement2'
import MyElement3 from './MyElement3'
import MyElement4 from './MyElement4'
export default { MyBaseComponent, MyElement1, MyElement2, MyElement3, MyElement4 };
```

И теперь можно импортировать из `MyBaseComponenеKit.js`

```
import { MyBaseComponent, MyElement1, MyElement2, MyElement3, MyElement4 } from './MyBaseComponenеKit.js'
```

**Другой вариант:**

Можно просто создать компонент Basic:

```
import React from 'react';

import MyElement1 from './MyElement1';
import MyElement2 from './MyElement2';
import MyElement3 from './MyElement3';
import MyElement4 from './MyElement4';

const Basic = () => (
    <MyElement1>
        <MyElement2 />
        <MyElement3 />
        <MyElement4 />
    </MyElement1>
);

export default Basic;
```

Comment: В принципе да, это решает проблему кучи строчек, но за счёт появления одной длинной :) А можно и ее как-то сократить?

Comment: Добавил еще один вариант.

Comment: второй вариант не очень :( У меня много таких вещей будет и мне не хотелось бы каждый раз где я буду формировать некоторый блок писать несколько импортов. Вот я и подумал, чтобы каждый раз мне всего лишь один импорт писать было бы (ну как в тех же c++ и подобных языках)

Comment: Кстати первый вариант тоже почему-то не сработал :( `Attempted import error: 'MyElement1' is not exported from '../MyElements/AllMyElements'.`